# Create a local monitoring agent that communicates with an API on demand

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to create a monitoring agent for applications and services running locally on the machine. Then send this information to an API in order to display it in an administrator dashboard. The basic requirements are :

- to constantly monitor a list of applications that i get from the API database (I am also in charge of creating the API)
- to be able to add and remove applications from the list programmatically - constantly update the list of applications to monitor
- send the updated list to the API on-demand basis

Based on these requirements I managed to create a [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) [worker-service](/questions/tagged/worker-service) in [.net-core](/questions/tagged/.net-core) 6.0 that check every 5 minutes the status of the windows services locally. And every 10 minutes it will execute an HTTP Get request on the API in order to update the list of applications. For this, I used `HttpClient` package.

All these I managed to execute in one Thread and it works fine. The information from the last of applications status check is kept in memory until the next run, then updated on next run. I made this decision because I don't need to keep every check in memory, only the ones the client requested.

When I added a new class that implements `HttpListener` - to listen for requests from the API, I noticed that the console blocks itself to listen for requests and does not execute any other commands. I suppose that I need a second thread to execute as a server and respond to API requests. I have to pass it the applications list from the other worker to be send back as JSON in response.

Below is my `ExecuteAsync` method.

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
        // Start the server class - HttpListener
        _listening.StartServer(prefixe);

        //Get the list of applications from the API 
        var remoteList = await _monitoring.GetJsonHttpClient(_url, _httpClient);
                
        //update local list with new applications to monitor
        if (remoteList.Count() != localList.Count())
        {
            elems = _monitoring.CompareTwoListElements(localList, remoteList);
        }
        // Check the status of applications 
        await _monitoring.GetWindowsServiceStatus(localList);
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_config.MonitoringTimeInSeconds), stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

This solution seems like a possible one to be implemented, but I don't know if it's a optimal solution in my case, considering that one thread will act as a client to retrieve the applications list, and another as as server to listen for requests and send the updated list.

Do you have any suggestions or solutions on how I could achieve this in most efficient way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use IHTTPClientFactory and PeriodicTimer.
This is a sample project for your question . (https://github.com/roozbeh-hoseiny/MonitoringAgent)